How to log Web APIs called by a script in Puppeteer?
Disclaimer: I am talking about Web APIs here not network calls.
I am using Puppeteer with Chromium to execute JS scripts in headless mode and I am trying to find out what browser APIs a script is calling by executing it instead of statically analyzing it.
Does Puppeteer provide functionality to do that or will I have to modify Chromium's source code to achieve that?
A simple example I would like would be visiting a site and logging any browser APIs that the site's JavaScript calls.
